# is a CSV with equal sign valid?

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula

I just got a CSV input file to be processed, which has an equal-sign before the first delimiting quote, and wondered if this is valid and has any purpose. Example (simplified):

```
"2"
"3"
="4"
```

After reading some postings like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27363394/1845672) I experimented with a CSV like this:

```
"2"
"3"
="A1+A2"
```

and:

```
"2"
"3"
"=A1+A2"
```

It seems that both Excel and LibreOffice silently ignore the equal-sign before the quote, and nicely treat the equal-sign after the quote as the flag for a formula. However, I could not find any documentation about this.

(For Excel, this CSV needs to be saved with the .txt extension, and opened with control-O)

I am inclined to call the CSV with equal-sign before the open quote as an error that is easy to deal with when reading this file, but still wondering if there is more to say about this.

Comment: If you import a field value like `="A1+A2"` then the cell will display `A1+A2` as text while the formula (in the Formula Bar) remains `="A1+A2"`. If you get too adventurous with attempting to bring in formulas as a CSV field, you may run into `#NAME!` errors. That's not to say that formulas cannot be brought in but I've found that occasionally you need a Find & Replace for = to = to 'assert' the formula as a true formulas and not text-that-looks-like-a-formula.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is used by Excel to avoid the loss of leading zero's.

For example, if you have a field in your csv file like this: `0123456`, Excel will treat it as a number and lose the leading zero.

Saving it as `="0123456"` solves this problem.

Using `"0123456"` won't help either, because quotes are not there to indicate a text field, but to escape possible delimiters inside fields.

Just like having `sep=;` on the first line to make Excel use the right seperator, the `=""` is also 'non-standard', or better: *Excel specific*, because there is no real standard for csv files.

Comment: Excellent! That is even more a feature than just treating a number as a string

Answer (score 7):

Excel isn't ignoring `=` in `="4"` or `="A1 + A2"`, it is treating it as a constant formula.

If you open the csv file that looks like:

```
"2"
"3"
="4"
="A1+A2"
"=A1+A2"
```

in Excel the result looks like:

[image]

Note how `A3` holds the formula `="4"` rather than just the number 4.

Comment: Hard to decide which answer is better, I chose the other, but yours is very useful. +1

Comment: No problem, I also upvoted the accepted answer -- the link to the standard was helpful.

Comment: I noted also that `A3` is left aligned like a string, because the formula returns a string

Answer (score 5):

There is no official standard for CSV. As it says at [Comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values),

> An official standard for the CSV file format does not exist, but RFC 4180 provides a *de facto* standard for many aspects of it.

Looking at the [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), a field is either escaped or non-escaped. The escaped field has a BNF defined like this:

```
escaped = DQUOTE *(TEXTDATA / COMMA / CR / LF / 2DQUOTE) DQUOTE
```

Since the equals sign is not a part of the escaped characters, it may be like the "Free Parking" in Monopoly: The rules say nothing regarding it, but the *de facto* standard is to place $500 under it.

Comment: This page, http://www.creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm, talks about the way that Microsoft handles the equals sign. But it refers to leading zeroes, not equations.

Comment: I guessed something like you said (+1) and commented this way in http://superuser.com/a/318421/238666

Answer (score 1):

If you have a **.csv** file with the following contents:

```
"2"
"3"
="4"
```

and open it in Excel, you will see:

[image]

As you see. Excel discards the double quotes on the first two items and converts the third item into a formula.

That is how Excel functions.

If you want to get the the exact text into Excel *(retaining the double quotes)* you could use a macro.

Comment: Thanks. Like others just said, the = starts a formula with the effect that the numeric content is treated like a string.