# How to check if csv files contains a formula?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

After browsing a file I have to check if a csv file contains a formula or not in typescript or javascript.
Please help with an npm module or a function, as I need to protect a file from CSV Injection before uploading a file. The below code is what I have tried so far, it is just giving me the string-like #VALUE!, #NAME!, etc. instead I want =B1+C1

```
var files = e.target.files; 
var file = files[0];
if(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onload = (event: any) => {
        var csv = event.target.result;
        var string =  <string>csv ;
        if(string.replace(/\s+/, "").includes(',-') == true) {
            this.service.openSnackBar('PLEASE UPLOAD A VALID FILE','');
        } else if (string.includes("+") == true || string.includes("=")  == true) {
            this.service.openSnackBar('PLEASE UPLOAD A VALID FILE','');
            e.target.value = '';
        } else {
            // if valid upload to server
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was surprised to hear that CSVs *could* have embedded functions - I always thought that CSVs were simply text files, and relatively "safe" from vulnerabilities.

This is from OWASP (the Open Web Application Security Project):

> https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/CSV_Injection
>
> This attack is difficult to mitigate, and explicitly disallowed from
> quite a few bug bounty programs. To remediate it, ensure that no cells
> begin with any of the following characters:
>
> - Equals to (“=”)
> - Plus (“+”)
> - Minus (“-“)
> - At (“@”)

So that's probably a good place to start:

1. Read your .csv a line at a time and parse into columns (e.g. `string.split(',')`)
2. Ensure no column begins with any of the four characters above: =, +, - or @

Also read this post: [Is there a way to programmatically insert formulas into a csv file using vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048316/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-insert-formulas-into-a-csv-file-using-vb-net#)

Comment: not so trivial as each cell can be e.g. quoted or not so simple split won't do the job